# Create Co-occurrence matrix with bigrams

Tags: r, nlp, sparse-matrix, text-mining, text2vec

I am looking to create a co-occurrence matrix with bigrams in stead of unigrams from a single string. I am referring the following links

http://text2vec.org/glove.html

https://tm4ss.github.io/docs/Tutorial_5_Co-occurrence.html#3_statistical_significance

I want to create  the matrix and traverse it to create dataset as follows

```
Trem1     Term2     Score
```

The biggest catch being traversing the sentence with bigrams. Any help on this would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify your bigrams and create the co-occurence matrices. Below are some (really) simple examples. Choose 1 package and do everything with that one. Both quanteda and text2vec can use multiple cores / threads. Traversing over the resulting co-occurence matrices can be done with reshape2::melt, like this `reshape2::melt(as.matrix(my_cooccurence_matrix))`.

```
txt <- c("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
         "The dog jumped and ate the fox.")
```

using quanteda to create a feature co-occurrence matrix:

```
library(quanteda)
toks <- tokens(char_tolower(txt), remove_punct = TRUE, ngrams = 2)
f <- fcm(toks, context = "document")

Feature co-occurrence matrix of: 14 by 14 features.
14 x 14 sparse Matrix of class "fcm"
             features
features      the_quick quick_brown brown_fox fox_jumped jumped_over over_the the_lazy lazy_dog the_dog dog_jumped jumped_and and_ate
  the_quick           0           1         1          1           1        1        1        1       0          0          0       0
  quick_brown         0           0         1          1           1        1        1        1       0          0          0       0
  brown_fox           0           0         0          1           1        1        1        1       0          0          0       0
  fox_jumped          0           0         0          0           1        1        1        1       0          0          0       0
  jumped_over         0           0         0          0           0        1        1        1       0          0          0       0
  over_the            0           0         0          0           0        0        1        1       0          0          0       0
  the_lazy            0           0         0          0           0        0        0        1       0          0          0       0
  lazy_dog            0           0         0          0           0        0        0        0       0          0          0       0
  the_dog             0           0         0          0           0        0        0        0       0          1          1       1
  dog_jumped          0           0         0          0           0        0        0        0       0          0          1       1
  jumped_and          0           0         0          0           0        0        0        0       0          0          0       1
  and_ate             0           0         0          0           0        0        0        0       0          0          0       0
  ate_the             0           0         0          0           0        0        0        0       0          0          0       0
  the_fox             0           0         0          0           0        0        0        0       0          0          0       0
             features
features      ate_the the_fox
  the_quick         0       0
  quick_brown       0       0
  brown_fox         0       0
  fox_jumped        0       0
  jumped_over       0       0
  over_the          0       0
  the_lazy          0       0
  lazy_dog          0       0
  the_dog           1       1
  dog_jumped        1       1
  jumped_and        1       1
  and_ate           1       1
  ate_the           0       1
  the_fox           0       0
```

using text2vec to create a feature co-occurrence matrix:

```
library(text2vec)
i <- itoken(txt)
v <- create_vocabulary(i, ngram = c(2L, 2L))
vectorizer <- vocab_vectorizer(v) 
f2 <- create_tcm(i, vectorizer)

14 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 14 column names ‘the_lazy’, ‘and_ate’, ‘The_quick’ ... ]]

the_lazy    . . . 0.25 1.0 . 0.2 0.3333333 .         .   1.0000000 .         0.5000000 .        
and_ate     . . . .    .   1 .   .         0.5000000 1.0 .         0.3333333 .         0.5000000
The_quick   . . . 0.50 .   . 1.0 0.3333333 .         .   0.2000000 .         0.2500000 .        
brown_fox   . . . .    0.2 . 1.0 1.0000000 .         .   0.3333333 .         0.5000000 .        
lazy_dog.   . . . .    .   . .   0.2500000 .         .   0.5000000 .         0.3333333 .        
jumped_and  . . . .    .   . .   .         0.3333333 0.5 .         0.5000000 .         1.0000000
quick_brown . . . .    .   . .   0.5000000 .         .   0.2500000 .         0.3333333 .        
fox_jumped  . . . .    .   . .   .         .         .   0.5000000 .         1.0000000 .        
the_fox.    . . . .    .   . .   .         .         1.0 .         0.2000000 .         0.2500000
ate_the     . . . .    .   . .   .         .         .   .         0.2500000 .         0.3333333
over_the    . . . .    .   . .   .         .         .   .         .         1.0000000 .        
The_dog     . . . .    .   . .   .         .         .   .         .         .         1.0000000
jumped_over . . . .    .   . .   .         .         .   .         .         .         .        
dog_jumped  . . . .    .   . .   .         .         .   .         .         .         .
```